# I can't extend "Assembly" class with netcore

Tags: c#

I want extend the class Assembly like this :

```
using System.Reflection;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ShadowAssembly : Assembly
    {
        public override IEnumerable<TypeInfo> DefinedTypes { get { return null; } }
        public override IEnumerable<Module> Modules { get { return null; } }
    }
}
```

I use .NetStandard 1.6

```
{
  "dependencies": { "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1-*", ...},
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": { "imports": "dnxcore50" }
  }...
}
```

But I have the error :

```
CS1729 C# 'Assembly' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Why i have this error ? When i look source for Assembly class, it's just an abstract class without any constructor...

Ans if it's normal, how can i skirt this probleme ? (I don't find RealProxy in dotnetcore.)

Comment: Which source file are you looking at?

Comment: I look in metadata (F12) with visual studio and here :

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.cs